# Frequency Counter in Verilog

Tags: verilog, counter, vivado

Trying to implement a freq counter in Verilog.
What I need is a clock input, a count output, and a reset input.
The behaviour should be like this:

- an internal reg or wire variable counts the clock pulses applied to the clock input
- whenever a reset pulse comes, it should transfer the count value to output to keep there until the next clock pulse comes, and reset the internal variable.

A simple code is given below:

```
module counter(

input rst,
input clk,

output [31:0] countout
//output [31:0] count
);

wire rst;
wire clk;

reg [31:0] countout=0;
reg [31:0] count=0; 

always @ (posedge clk)
    begin
        count = count + 1'b1;
    end

always @ ( posedge rst )
    begin
        countout = count;
    end

always @ ( negedge rst )
    begin
        count = 0;
    end
endmodule
```

However, Vivado won't allow this as the count variable is a multi-driven net. Apparently, *count* cannot be changed in 2 different always block. Do you have any idea how I can implement this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a re-write of your code down there. It is re-written with accordance to the industry practices.

```
module counter(

input rst,
input clk,

output wire [31:0] countout // should be wire for assign.
//output [31:0] count
);

wire rst;
wire clk;

reg [31:0] countout; // = 0 -- do not initialize it here
reg [31:0] count; // = 0 

  always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst)
    begin
      if (rst == 0) 
        count <= 0;
      else
        count <= count + 1'b1;
    end

assign  countout = count;

endmodule
```

As you memtioned, driving 'count' from 2 differrent always block is not suported by synthesis tools and creates races in simulation. To avoid it, all driving of the variable must be done withing a singel always block, as in my example.

According to your code, you tried to implement an asynchronous reset for the counter. This functionality is implemented in my example using common practices with negedge of rst and the `if` statement in the block.

You do not need to use any additional flop to drive the 'countout' output. A simple `assign` statement is sufficient. In verilog you just need to be sure that lhs is a *wire*.

And, you should have used non-blocking assignments `<=` while creating flops.

Also, do not initialize variables at declarations. This also creates multiple drivers and might not be synthesizable.

When dealing wiht verilog, remember that you describe a hardware which consists of devices and connections. Every always block essentially defines a separate device with inputs and outputs. 'assign' and module ports represent connections between those devices.

Below is a simple testbench which can help you to test your counter:

```
module tb;
  reg rst;
  reg clk;
  wire[31:0] count;
  integer i;

  counter counter(rst, clk, count);
  
initial begin 
  
  // print counter
  $monitor(count);
  
  clk = 0;
  
  // toggle reset
  rst = 1;
  #5 rst = 0;
  #5 rst = 1;
  
  // run 5 clock cycles
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i = i+1) 
    #5 clk = ~clk;
  
  // done
  $finish;
end
endmodule
```

Comment: As I see, this version does NOT buffer `countout`, so it's value can't be used the way the asker wants.

Comment: @Sasszem There is no need to *buffer* countout. It is just a connection between count which is a register and the rest of the world. In the OP's code it is supposed to be flopped at *posedge rst* which makes no sense.  This would cause *countout* to stick at '0' after reset is done and not updated at all after it.

Comment: nope, it makes sense in his/her code, as it's written at rising edge, and the counter is cleared at falling edge, so *after* the value is stored.
Storing of a value *is* needed or you can't process it later, as it's get reset or changed.

Comment: @Sasszem are you talking about `count` or `countout`?

Comment: `countout` is updated to `count` on the rising edge, before the later is cleared 0. The asker's original code kept this as a buffer, so using it between counts was fine, as it stored the last count value. This answer's code does not come with the same behaviour, as `countout` is assigned to `count` (is assign to reg even valid?), thus the same logic must be done outside of the module.

Comment: rising edge of what? What does rising edge of 'rst' do? There is only a single rising edge of reset dufing the whole simulation. It will *buffer* a value of `0`.

Comment: In the original code of the asker, there was both `posedge rst` and `negedge rst` `always` blocks, which you have merged and dropped the `posedge rst`.
You also removed the buffering from `countout`, and made it a `wire` (but also a `reg`, you kept the original declaration too). You did not think that the buffering was intentional, which it possibly have been. Also, you now say your version does buffering, so please point me to the part of your code that does it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your design.

First, vivado will find 3 clocks :

- `clk` with posedge
- `rst` with posedge
- `rst` with falling edge.

I think you need only one clock.

Then you should write your process like it :

```
always @ (posedge clk)
begin
        // your code here
end
```

Second, you should use non-blocking assignment `<=` for synchronous register.

Then, as I understand the behaviour of rst is not really a reset but a simple input «button». And you need to know if edge occur.

I think you should change confusing name of `rst` by something like `btn`. And you should detect rising edge and falling edge saving previous value like it :

```
input btn;

reg btn_old, btn_rise, btn_fall;

always @ (posedge clk)
begin
    btn_rise <= 1'b0;
    btn_fall <= 1'b0;
    if(!btn_old && btn) begin
        btn_rise <= 1'b1;
    end
    if(btn_old && !btn) begin
        btn_fall <= 1'b1;
    end
    btn_old <= btn;
```

Then you can use `btn_fall` and `btn_rise` for your counter.

Comment: This makes the reset or button be synchronous, which might not be what the asker wants.